# Symfony2 Forms prevent changing entity's field

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I'm looking for a way to bind entity to a form, but I need a specific field of it to be mapped (displayed), but not modified by the user submitting the form.

What I have checked so far:

1. Using disabled attribute - it's not being submitted and entity's field is set to null
2. Using HTML readonly attribute - it can still be modified by manipulating HTML
3. Using read_only field option - same as above

My field is a checkbox, but I'd prefer a generic solution for that kind of fields, because I'll have more of them in the future.

I would also like to avoid additional query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The 1st & 3th solutions are not good.

I had the same issue a while ago. This is what I did to solve it:

I used the 2nd solution, and since you have the entity in the application, you can simply override any value the user had changed by manipulating the HTML (whitch is a risk that should be handled).

or, you could draw a HTML checkbox that is not mapped (with random id and name), and it will be not mapped to you entity.

Comment: With unmapped checkbox - the data will not be passed to it, am I right?

Comment: yap, when mapping the formData to the entity, only the matching names get mapped.

Comment: I think I will just override the template for my entity and display the property in span, without having the form field for that property.

Comment: yeah, that's what i'm saying. detach the property from FormType, and draw a HTML checkbox just for display

Comment: Check out my answer. I know I initially didn't want to make checks in code, but I think event listener (or perhaps a subscriber would be more suitable) is viable way to handle just that with no template manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the right solution to that problem. It's not very flexible, but converting it to extension should make it fairly easy to deal with. The basic version I created just now can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/pzaj2/8f2676870349914ed96257dff712a512). A little explanation:

1. Make the field with option `mapped` set to `false`
2. create event handler function (setUnmappedField)
3. attach EventListener to both PRE_SET_DATA and SUBMIT events.

PRE_SET_DATA makes sure the field has a correct value when initially rendering the form.
SUBMIT makes sure the field's value is reverted back to the initial value even if user changed it before submitting the form.

Disabled and readonly attributes are here for UI/UX, it will work without these attributes as well.

Feel free to use it to build a form extension if you need one. I will probably build an extension to make it more flexible later, once I need it.

@EDIT

I just realised this can be done easier - leaving the field mapped! [updated](https://gist.github.com/pzaj2/b4d7fafe82236d0c0459974e512e2c0e) gist here. No need for PRE_SET_DATA listener and `mapped=false`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do a combination of 1 and 2 . See below for sample

```
 ->add('trainings', 'entity', array(
                'label'=> 'Upcoming training(s)',
                'choice_label' => 'CompleteTitle',
                'multiple' => 'true',
                'expanded' => 'true',
                'by_reference'=>false,
                'class' => 'TrainingBundle:Trainings' ,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                    return $er->getTrainingByParentId($options['parent_id']);
                },
            )
        )
        ->add('PastTrainings', 'entity', array(
                'label'=> 'Past trainings',
                'choice_label' => 'CompleteTitle',
                'multiple' => 'true','expanded' => 'false',
                'disabled' => 'true',
                'class' => 'TrainingBundle:Training' ,'mapped'=>false,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                    return $er->getTrainingByParentId($options['parent_id']);
                },


            )
```